# jQuery load() div that contains a script

Tags: jquery, load, getscript

I'm trying to load a div that contains a javascript link into another div on another page (http://www.thebigkerbang.com/brand-storytellers/clients/xour-clients.html) with load(). I know load() strips out the script tag but I'm getting a bit confused with the $.getscript. I can load the div fine as I can see it in the code inspector.

**loading the div from this page:**

```
 <div id="beautific_hype_container" style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;width:700px;height:500px;"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="beautific.hyperesources/beautific_hype_generated_script.js?10913"></script> 
  </div>
```

**into the div from this page:**

```
<div class = "edgeContent"></div>
```

**with:**

```
 $('document').ready(function(){
  $(".beautific").click(function(){
    $(".edgeContent").load('beautific/beautific.html #beautific_hype_container', function() {   
    $.getScript('beautific/beautific.hyperesources/beautific_hype_generated_script.js?10913');
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: How are you getting confused? What is not working?

Comment: Thanks Fredrik. That still only loads 
`<div id="beautific_hype_container" style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;width:700px;height:500px;"> 
      </div>`and strips out the script.

Comment: Strange, I use that method myself and the script is not filtered out. Then again - I don't reference the script with `src`, I have it inline .

Comment: If you look in the browser developer tools, what is the response recieved from the server?

Comment: Apologies Fredrik, it seems to be pulling in the div with the script now. (http://www.thebigkerbang.com/brand-storytellers/clients/xour-clients.html) when you click on the first button below. :) Thanks for your patience and I know know a little about $.ajax :)

Comment: ps ;) When I use the second button to load another div (they are going to be a few Hype portfolio animations), will the previous div automatically be unloaded?

Comment: Since it loads into the same div, the old data should be discarded. Any loaded script resource might be cached by the browser though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it with an `$.ajax()` call:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $(".beautific").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "beautific/beautific.html #beautific_hype_container",
    }).done(function ( data ) {
      $(".edgeContent").html(data);
    });
  });
});
```

That way your script tag will also not be filtered out.